# Movie about Koschei the Immortal

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, folklore

I remember watching what I think was a Soviet or some other Eastern European movie about the mythical Koschei the Immortal. It was in color and ended with the characters finding Koschei's soul inside a needle and I think breaking that needle. When they do that, Koschei falls to the ground and dies. What I remember about his death scene is that his body just kind of explodes in several places, starting either with the head or the feet (I don't remember). After the characters witness Koschei's death, they cross themselves. I remember nothing else about the movie. Can anyone identify this film?

Comment: Maybe "Fire, Water, and Brass Pipes"?

Comment: Was the movie animated, or live-action?

Comment: The movie was Live-Action.

Comment: No, it's not Fire, Water, and Brass Pipes.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this might be the movie, because it fits your description. Minute 35 is the part with needle and death. Tell me if it looks familiar:

The name in the video is Сказки : Царевна-лягушка , from 1954

Koschei is traditional enemy in Russian / USSR animation, as can be seen in the below video at 3 minute mark (Taken from the 1996 VHS "Classic Fairy Tales From Around The World." Animated in Russia. English dub):

Multiple examples of him in Soviet cinematography here:

Comment: No, this is not it. The movie I watched was live-action, not an animated cartoon.